# TeXView rerenders after setState in flutter_tex

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-tex

I have this chunk of code in my flutter app that renders KaTeX

```
TeXView(
                renderingEngine: widget.renderingEngine,
                child: TeXViewDocument(chatMessage.messageContent,
                  style: TeXViewStyle(
                    contentColor: Colors.white,
                    fontStyle: TeXViewFontStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      fontFamily: 'Nunito'
                    ),
                  )
                ),
              )
```

but after each setState, it rerenders, which I don't want, because it takes too much time and recourses. How can I stop it from rerendering ever?

I tried finding anything about stopping a container or a widget from rerendering but could not find anything